# Rollback an entire stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure with multiple update statements.I dont want to use try catch.How can I rollback the stored procedure and get back the original table?

can something like this work -

begin transaction t1
spName
rollback transaction t1

Comment: You can wrap the body of the stored procedure in a single transaction.

Comment: Why don't you want to use try catch. Your proc will basically do nothing except let you debug syntax issues.

Comment: The queries in the stored procedure will be fired every  week through a job.Now while testing if I want to get back the original table after executing the stored prc,how do I get back  the original table? #scsimon you are correct bt my requirement is something else

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can wrap everything into a sproc into a transaction

```
begin tran
exec testproc

commit tran
--rollback tran --for condition
```

It works fine even for commit as well rollback

If for inside the sproc you need to open another transaction then you need to capture

```
DECLARE @vTranCount   INT = @@TRANCOUNT

--Commit
IF (@vTranCount = 0 AND @@TRANCOUNT <> 0) COMMIT TRANSACTION --Commit if the Tran is created by this sproc

--rollback during catch
IF(@vTranCount = 0 AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION --Rollback if the Tran is created by this sproc
```